# Grabbing first and last field with regex delimeter using perl one-liner

Tags: regex, perl

I need to parse a file and grab certain fields from it using a regular expression as part of the delimiter.  I thought I can use perl to do this(?).  The problem is I can't get it to work properly.  Here's a one liner which I thought would allow me to print fields that are separated by one more white spaces (in this case one or more space):

```
bash_prompt> perl -anF'/ +/' -e 'print "$F[0], $F[-1]\n"' build_outputfile
```

The output file is from a makefile.

Here, I want to print out the first token, and the last token.  So in my case which compiler was used and which file was compiled.  Perhaps there's a better way to do it, but now I'm bothered as to why my perl one liner does not work.

Anyways,  the regular expression '/ +/ does not appear to work.  I get some unexpected output.  Perhaps F does not actually want a regular expression?  When I replace F's argument  with '/ /' that contains one space, I still don't get a expected output.

Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Here's some test code for you to try.  Save it in a file:

```
g++ -c  -g  -Wall -I/codedir/src/CanComm/include -I/home/codemonkey/workspace/thirdparty/Boost -Wno-deprecated SCMain.cpp
g++ -c -g  -Wall -I./object/include -I./wrapper/include -I./Properties/include -I./Messaging/include -I/codedir/src/Logging/sclog/include ./object/SCObject.cpp ./object/RandNumGenerator.cpp ./object/ScannerConstraints.cpp ./object/ThreadSync.cpp ./object/SCData.cpp ./object/AirScanData.cpp ./object/ClusterData.cpp ./object/WarmupData.cpp ./object/SCCommand.cpp ./object/ScanCommands.cpp ./object/RCCommands.cpp ./object/ReconData.cpp ./object/UICommTool.cpp ./object/UIMsg.cpp ./object/UI2SCConversion.cpp ./object/RCMsg.cpp ./object/RCMessageInfo.cpp ./object/Utils.cpp ./object/ZBackupTable.cpp ./object/ZBackupFactory.cpp
g++ -c -g  -Wall -I./Properties/include -I/codedir/src/Logging/sclog/include -I./object/include -I/home/codemonkey/workspace/thirdparty/Boost  ./Properties/PropertyMap.cpp
```

Comment: Well, I thought of one way to fix my problem.  I can explicitly split each line instead of having perl automatically do it:

    perl -ne '@f=split(/ +/); print "$f[0], $f[-1]\n"'

It's not as compact as using the -F argument but it works.  Does anyone have an answer to the -F argument version?

thanks.

Comment: `perl -lnwe '$,=", "; print /^\S+|\S+$/g'` might do the trick too, and might be faster than a full split (though I doubt it will be noticeable with such small input).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `perldoc perlrun`:

> -Fpattern
>
> specifies the pattern to split on if -a is also in effect.
>   The pattern may be surrounded by "//", "", or '', otherwise it will be put in single quotes. **You can't use literal whitespace in the pattern.**

I have to admit: What a thoroughly arbitrary restriction!

Comment: Indeed what a crazy restriction!!  Now I know, -F stands for Funny.  I should go with my clunkier method.  I'll most likely forget this over time.  Hehehe....   Anwyays, awesome answer.  Thanks.  I can finally not be bothered by this anymore.

Comment: @Badministrator: You're welcome. (By the way, you can upvote helpful answers, and/or select them as the correct answer... ;-)

Comment: +1. Fortunately, you can work around this by writing a space as `\x20`; so, `-anF'/\x20+/'`.

Answer (score 2):

For your problem you don't actually need to specify a pattern as the default which is space might do you good enough.

```
perl -anle 'print "$F[0], $F[-1]"' build_outputfile
```

Comment: You're right about the default pattern being OK here. But if `-n` is given then Perl reads input from `<>`, which will read from any files specified on the command line -- it only reads from stdin if there are none, so it's not necessary to use `<` piping. Also my answer already gave the explanation about `-F`. Please edit.

Comment: I will give you +1 for seeing that default split is fine, but -1 for thinking you need to pipe through stdin.

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex pattern should be like this:

```
'/\s+/'
```

**\s** means to match any whitespace

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!  But why doesn't the regexp that I use not work?  In this case I want to split on the space-char, and not on whitespace characters?

Comment: The space char **is** a whitespace. **\s** will match either a space, newline or a tab character

Comment: That is the same as using the default split, though, which means just skipping the -F switch.